# Why is asp:LinkButton server side event doesn't fire when clientClick returns true

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, events, server-side

I have asp:GridView with LinkButton:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="Cancel"  runat="server" OnClick="Cancel_Click" OnClientClick="return confirmCancel(this);">cancel</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I want the server side event to occur only when the confirmCancel returns true.
but I have a strange problem:

if the function explicitly returns true -

```
return true;
```

the event occurs.

if the function explicitly returns false -

```
return false;
```

the event does not occurs.

but if the function returns variables with true or false -

```
return x;
```

the event does not occur anyway.

I put debugger and saw that the value of x is true or false and not undefined or something.
what is the problem?

confirmCancel:

```
function confirmCancel(sender) {

        var msg = "are you sure you want to cancel?"
        var x = myConfirm(msg, sender);
        return x;
}
```

myConfirm:

```
function myConfirm(msg, sender) {
            if ($('#myConfirm').hasClass("hide")) {
                $('#myConfirm').removeClass("hide");
                $('#myConfirm p').text(msg);
                $("#myConfirm input#btn-ok").unbind("click").click(function () {
                    $(sender).click();
                    return false;
                });
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#alertify').addClass("hide");
                return true;
            }                
        }
```

how can I solve it?

Comment: You wanna just show confirm message on LinkButton click ?

Comment: yes. I want the user to confirm cancelling by custom confirm box.

Comment: show your `confirmCancel` function code.

Comment: please look at my edit (I tested it and I know those functions return always the correct value).

Comment: There are a typo in your code `'`, I think you don't need `$(sender).click();` just return `true` and `false` is enough.

Comment: I think I have to explain my idea: first time, before the user see the confirm box, I want anyway to return false. next time, when the confirm is visible, I want to return true only when the user clicks on $("#myConfirm input#btn-ok").

Answer (score 0):

You can use a workaround till you discover the problem:

```
function confirmCancel(sender) {

        var msg = "are you sure you want to cancel?"
        var x = myConfirm(msg, sender);
        if (x == true)
        {
             return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but I tried it and nothing changed.